# What to test after changing only the source and target version

Tags: java

We have been following the official [Java migration guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) to upgrade our application from Java 6 to Java 8. Unfortunately we haven't set source and target version to 1.8 to prevent the usage of new language features.

So currently we are compiling and executing our application with `JDK 1.8 / JRE 1.8` but set source and target level to `1.6`.

Nevertheless, we now even want to level up the source and target level for our applications to 1.8.

Does setting those properties only changes the allowed features for the compilation and the binary format of the classes or does the configuration changes the semantics of the application? We expect that there shouldn't be any known issues or incompatibility when updating the source and target version to a higher version, when staying on the same JRE for execution and JDK for compilation.

Comment: This is where you hope you have good unit tests coverage.

Comment: If you have done extensive VM tuning this should be checked since there are lot of changes in GC and other internal implementations. Many configuration options have changed.

Comment: If you find the answer to the question satisfactory please close it so the other members of the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Compatibility Guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) at the source level, JDK 8 is **strongly** compatible with previous versions however there're corner cases (explained in the guide).

What you refer to as "changes to the semantics" is a result of not only behavioural incompatibilities, including changes in API implementation (for example this [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021591) which is fixed in 8), but also the platform itself.

Therefore your code compiles and runs, but it might have bugs.

Bottom line, only your test cases can guarantee the smooth transition.

**Update**

- Changing source compatibility to 8 does not break compile of existing source which is in lower level, e.g. 6.
- Changing binary compatibility changes the version of the generated bytecode, i.e. compiled `.class` files, and obviously you compatible runtime environment.
- JRE is backward compatible when deals with bytecode. You can run the new bytecode (e.g. your compiled source) along with old bytecode (e.g. your dependencies).
- You might experience some semantic changes due to different platform and API implementations, including runtime libraries.
- Some of the semantic changes are not easy to catch even with test cases (my personal was experience with *Java Crypto API* and SSL).

Comment: The problem is not compatiblity with the behavioural changes of the JRE, since we have already gone through the guidelines and tested our application with the JRE 8, but changing the source and target level after migrating to the new JRE.

Comment: @AlexN In that case the short answer as you've guessed is: it doesn't cause incompatibility. However, I'm wondering why you want to change the source level since you've already written it? The reason I'm asking is that I had the same problem with a legacy code and had to upgrade from 6 to 8 (only the JRE)  due to SSL requirements.

Comment: Because without source and target level we cannot use for example lambdas which are mandatory for the usage of new libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> Does setting those properties only changes the allowed features for the compilation and the binary format of the classes or does the configuration changes the semantics of the application?

It can actually change the semantics of the Java language.  For example, the meaning of `@Overrides` changed between Java 5 and Java 6.  (I can't recall any changes like that between Java 6 and Java 8, but ....)

And of course:

- There will be library bug fixes.
- There will be cases where methods or classes are re-implemented (e.g. Arrays.sort and HashMap) with differences in unspecified aspects of library behavior.
- Changes to the JIT compiler can lead to native code being optimized differently which can lead to timing or memory model-related regressions in (your) buggy multi-threaded code.

In short, even though upgrading from one version to the next ... or just changing the `--source` or `--target` is usually innocuous, it can sometimes lead to problems that need to be fixed.

So ... test everything ... thoroughly.  Don't assume that it will all just work when you roll our the newer version.

Of course, it is advisable to read the lists of bug fixes and incompatibilities in the respective release notes.  But be aware that the lists may be incomplete, or that you won't realize that some fix impacts your code.  (Who knows / remembers every implementation detail of an large application written many years go?)  And be aware that the fixed bug lists in a new major release are incremental from a previous patch release.

---

The counterpoint is that, you can't just defer upgrading because.  The longer you put it off, the harder it becomes and the larger your codebase's technical debt becomes.  And you may find yourself having to do the upgrade in a panic; e.g. due to an unpatched security problem, an OS support issue, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly related to the topic of target and source. This depends on if your application is library which can be included in other projects. For example prior to AS3 you could not include libaries which where compiled with target and source `> 1.7` although the code semantics were exactly the same. Even if the library did not include any Java 8 features e.g. streams.

So that might be a "check mark".